# Use Koin test inside Spek tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, koin, spek

I just want to implement test using koin inside spek test, but just got error No value passed for parameter 'clazz'

```kotlin
object HomeViewModelTest : Spek({

    private val model by inject<HomeViewModel>() // ← this got error  No value passed for parameter 'clazz'
})
```

Comment: Do you have Koin bootstrapped, via a startKoin call somewhere?

Comment: yup startKoin is already call in beforeEachTest scope it similar to @get:Rule